# parse result of bash command

Tags: bash, parsing

I am new to bash scripting and am trying to parse out information from a whois result, specifically, the orgname and city fields.
Is the proper way to save the result in a string and then parse the string for the relevant information? like:

```
    RESULT=whois <ip>
    # parse RESULT
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To record the result: `RESULT=$( whois <ip> )`  The syntax you give attempts to run the command `<ip>` with the value of RESULT set to "whois" in the environment.

Comment: You can start parsing even before recording with `RESULT=$(whois <ip> | awk '/OrgName/ {print $0} /City/ {print $0}')`, which will only store in your variable the information you want.

Comment: Or even add `awk -F : '/OrgName/{print $2}' and so on, assuming the whois information is formatted the same way everywhere. Note: I just tried whois for a host that had neither an OrgName nor a City field, so you won't always be able to get this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, the `whois` output seems to be meant for humans, not machines, to read. Its format depends on which root domain you are interested in. For example, `whois uio.no` returns stuff like

```
NORID Handle...............: UIO2O-NORID
Type.......................: organization
Name.......................: UNIVERSITETET I OSLO
Id Type....................: organization_number
Id Number..................: 971035854
Registrar Handle...........: REG2-NORID
Post Address...............: Postboks 1059, Blindern
```

while `whois tasvideos.org` produces

```
Registrant ID:ACTR120531657
Registrant Name:Andres Delikat
Registrant Organization:tasvideos.org
Registrant Street1:5505G Creek Ridge Ln
Registrant Street2:
Registrant Street3:
Registrant City:Raleigh
```

This is just to show that parsing this stuff will depend on what you're looking at, and the solution I provide will not work in all cases. But the easiest way to extract this information is by calling `awk` and keeping its output. For the ".org" case, which is the one you probably want, it would be something like this:

```
info=$(whois $ip)
org=$(echo "$info" | awk -F : '$1=="Registrant Organization"{print $2}')
city=$(echo "$info" | awk -F : '$1=="Registrant City"{print $2}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful information!

Comment: If this solves your problem, remember to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

See this question:
[How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command)

```
cmd="yourcommand"
string=$($cmd)
echo $string
```